# Writing JUnit test on Collections

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, junit4

It will be helpful to get some ideas on how to write a JUnit test case with the following code. Not sure if this a proper question to ask but since I am starting to learn JUnit and couldn't understand where to start from.

Heres the following code where the program asks a user to input names and outputs the data by removing duplicates.

```
public class Q2 {
    public void readNames() {
        System.out.println("Please enter names seperated by newline, or type esc to stop");
        Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
        Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();

        String word;
        while (str.hasNextLine()) {
            word = str.nextLine();
            if (word != null) {
                word = word.trim();
                if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("esc")) {
                    break;
                }
                s.add(word);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The list contains - ");
        for (String str1 : s) {
            System.out.println(str1);
        }
        str.close();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Q2 answer = new Q2();
        answer.readNames();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your code uses System.in and System.out extensively, you might like to write tests that change the values of these before you start.

Comment: I have fixed test data for this. Say the dats is
apple
apple
orange
kiwi
esc

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to parameterize the method `readNames()` so that you can inject classes needed to test it.

```
public class Q2 {   
    public void readNames() {
        System.out.println("Please enter names seperated by newline, or type 
        esc to stop");
        Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
        Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
```

Change this to something like:

```
public class Q2 {   
    public void readNames( InputStream in ) {
        System.out.println("Please enter names seperated by newline, or type 
        esc to stop");
        Scanner str = new Scanner(in);
        Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
```

Now you can inject a stream which has some test vectors (words to read) into the method so you can test it.  Obviously you'll have make some modifications to the source code where you call that method.

Comment: Thanks but will that be helpful for a JUnit test using assertions?

Answer (score 0):

Each method in a class should perform a maximum of one task at a time. Your method readNames is doing three tasks.

1. Reading input
2. Processing input
3. Printing output.

Writing tests would be easier if you separate them into different methods. For example, readNames should perform only the processing of data and return the output. Another method should print the output.

Coming to actual question, if you have a method which has a Set as argument, in your test class you can simply create an object of Q2 class and call the method with sample data and assert on the return statement.